# Robot Framework: get selection from user keyword inside a user defined keyword throws error 'Keyword name cannot be empty'

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Resource    ../Tests/Main.robot
Resource    SSmthn.robot

Library    Dialogs
Library    Collections
*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***
Select Browser: User Input
    ${value} =    get selection from user    Select Browser    Begin Web Test with Chrome Browser    Begin Web Test with headlessChrome
    ${value}

Begin Web Test with Chrome Browser
    ${options}=    Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver.chrome.options'].Options()    sys
    Call Method     ${options}    add_argument    --disable-notifications
    ${driver}=    Create Webdriver    Chrome    options=${options}
    go to    ${URL}
    maximize browser window
    sleep    2sec

Begin Web Test with headlessChrome

    open browser    ${URL}    ${Browser}
    maximize browser window
    sleep    2sec

End Web Test
    close all browsers
```

Here Iam asking user for one of the 2 selections.

[image]

`${value}`: stores value from user selection but does not call the keyword selected by the user. What can I change here to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A keyword which name is stored in a variable can be executed by using the `Run Keyword` keyword from the BuiltIn library.

```
Select Browser: User Input
    ${value} =    get selection from user    Select Browser    Begin Web Test with Chrome Browser    Begin Web Test with headlessChrome
    Run Keyword    ${value}
```